# Laravel 4 Search Query with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying to have a search option for users to fill in and search multiple tables for orders, commissions, etc without having to reload the page. Never used AJAX before so if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong or help me get this working it would be very much appreciated! Right now when I click on the submit button nothing happens except for getting an 500 (Internal Server Error) message.

Here is my View (home):

```
 <div class="large-6 columns">
{{Form::open( array('route' => 'search', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'search_form'))}}      

        {{ Form::select('search_table',
                array(
                    'select'        => 'Search...',
                    'commissions'   => 'Search commissions',
                    'estimates'     => 'Search estimates',
                    'orders'        => 'Search orders',
                    'warranties'    => 'Search warranties',
        ), null, array('id' => 'search_table')) }}

        <div class="search_box" id="search_column_div">
            <!-- Search_column select goes here -->
        </div>

        <div id="search_input_div">
            <!-- Search_input text field goes here -->
        </div>

{{ Form::submit('Search', array('id' => 'search_button','class' => 'button expand radius search_button no_display'))}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
    <div id="search_results_div">
    </div>
</div>
```

Because the search has a lot of variables but I didn't want to make it take up a lot of space I have JS insert the next part of the query based on their previous selection. So they will start with the ability to pick a table to search, then a column, then they will have an input field to write what exactly they are searching for.

JS (where my problem probably is):

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#search_form').on('submit', function(){
        $.post(
            $(this).prop('action'),{
                "search_table":     $('#search_table').val(),
                "search_column":    $('#search_column').val(),
                "search_input":     $('#search_input').val(),
            },
            function(data){
                $('#search_results_div').html(data);
            },
            'json'
        );
        return false;
        });
});
```

Controller:

```
 public function searchPost(){
        $search_table   = Input::get('search_table');
        $search_column  = Input::get('search_column');
        $search_input   = Input::get('search_input');

        $search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
        return $search;
    }
```

And the Route:

```
/*Search Page for Ajax*/
Route::post('/search', array(
    'as'    => 'search',
    'uses'  => 'HomeController@searchPost'
));
```

Thanks again for your time and help! Please feel free to make suggestions for best practices!

Comment: The route you've posted is listening for GET requests but you're POSTing the AJAX request.

Comment: Good point, updated the question, but still getting the 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a start, you're didn't say what the problem was, but just looking at that code, you're setting `HomeController@searchPost` as the action for your post method, but your search method is actually `HomeController@search`.

You're also using the wrong variables. You're passing in `search_table`, `search_column` and `search_input` as the keys in your Javascript, but you're trying to read `table_searched`, `column_searched` and `input_searched` - so all those variables will always be nulls in your server-side code.

Your `$search` query will also always fail. `'%LIKE%'` is not valid SQL - the `%` need to go around the search term. What you really want is:

```
$search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
```

Try fixing all of those and see if it deals with your problem :)

Comment: Thanks, for clearing so much stuff up for me. I made the corrections you pointed out and now when I submit the page doesn't crash, which is a plus, but I get an "500 (Internal Server Error)" message. I know that usually means a general error that the page can't figure out what specifically is. Any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: Laravel should be giving you a very detailed stack trace when it crashes - don't you get an orange-and-black screen that details where the error is?

Comment: Usually I do, right now nothing happens when I click on the submit button except that in the web developer tools I see that error message.

Comment: So I'm guessing the code above is technically correct enough to not cause the page to break but doesn't do what I intended it to do which is to go search for something and place them in the "search_results_div" div.

Comment: If you're using Chrome's dev tools, you can inspect the content of the request. If Laravel dies on an AJAX request, it's smart enough to return a JSON representation of the error. http://cl.ly/image/0x1g1A132W2M

Comment: You might check the app/storage/logs/laravel.log out as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are several issues. I see that you've already made some changes but there are some more problems you need to fix. Your AJAX request is using a POST request but your route is listening for a GET request. Even once that's fixed, you'll need to included some sort of error handling or validation for the controller and database query before returning the result. After that you need to look at how you're handling what is being returned by the AJAX request.

The 500 error you're getting means that there's a problem with your server-side code. More than likely something isn't "wired-up" correctly. If you're having troubles getting a detailed error report, use "console.log()" to output what's returned via AJAX to the dev console. From there you can debug the problem.